# LoadLibrary fails if dll locked

Tags: c++, loadlibrary, locks

I designed multiple programs that try simultaneously take a lock on a file so that a master can be set from all programs. But this file is also a dll that the program must load when becomes master.

This is the code:

```
bool takeLock(){
    .....
    if ((handle = CreateFileA(path.c_str(),  GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
....
HMODULE lib = LoadLibraryA(path);
```

I choose GENERIC_WRITE because I thought LoadLibrary wouldn't write back to the dll. But it fails. It also fails on GENERIC_READ.

Is LoadLibrary sensible to locks?

Comment: Don't try to open/lock a DLL. If you want a mutex shared between some programs, create a named mutex.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. So LoadLibrary doesn't like locked files?

Comment: Right--the loader basically thinks it should get full ownership of every executable file (exe, dll, etc.) anytime it's in use.